# Insert data from a Python dictionary to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I want to insert dictionary data into mysql each key in its own field. I tried following code. But its wrong. Can any one help? I really appreciate. thanks so much :-)

```
d = {"spam": "1", etc,etc,"egg": "2"}
cols = d.keys()
vals = d.values()

stmt = "INSERT INTO table (%s) VALUES(%s)" % (
",".join(cols), ",".join(len(vals))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you call `len(vals)` ? Your code should work by simply removing that.

Comment: thanks I want to insert `single quote ` around values. How can I add ?

Comment: Probably not the prefered way, but you can do: `VALUES(\"%s\") ... % '", "'.join(vals);`